# How to fit a LinearLayout in a ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

Earlier on I asked a question [about how to reach the last item of a scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60510336/how-to-reach-the-last-items-of-a-scroll-view/60510966#60510966) and someone pointed out that I should be using NestedScrollView, at first it worked but now it's not what I want.

I want to fit my list of item in the ScrollView so only that part of the screen can be scrolled and the other parts stay at their place (the 3 TextView)
[image: frame design]

So basically my xml file is like this :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cl_framgnent_detail_apero"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context=".ui.home.AperoDetailFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_apero"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_apero"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ingredient_title_apero"
         />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/rv_apero_ingredient"
        android:layout_width="408dp"
        android:layout_height="603dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ingredient_title_apero"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ingredient_title_apero"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/vertical_layout_ingredient"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And in my Java code I try to populate my list with the following code :

```java
public class AperoDetailFragment extends Fragment {

    private View root;
    private Apero detailApero;

    public AperoDetailFragment(Apero apero) {
        this.detailApero = apero;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull final LayoutInflater inflater,
                             final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail_apero, container, false);

        TextView name = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.name_apero);
        name.setText(detailApero.getName());
        TextView date = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.date_apero);
        date.setText(detailApero.getDate());

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.vertical_layout_ingredient);
        LinearLayout a = new LinearLayout(root.getContext());
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        a.setLayoutParams(lparams);

        a.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            Button b = new Button(root.getContext());
            b.setText("Button " + i);
            a.addView(b);
        }
        ll.addView(a);

        return root;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the item are covering the whole screen instead of staying in the parent container (ScrollView) :

[image: real view]

How can I fit my list of item to stay in the parent ?

Answer (score 0):

If this is your actual code, then it might help to set constraints to the text views too.

Also, if your ScrollView has a fixed height, then you should remove either the top or bottom constraint. So if you want it to stick to the bottom, remove the top constraint.

Comment: yes this is my actual code, the items are all well placed except the fact that when I try to populate my  linear layout it appears out of the ScrollView as you can see on the screen shot

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with removing the ScrollView and using a ListView